# How can we create the custom event in magento

Tags: magento, events

i am new in magento and learning magento .Magento predefine event used with `predispatch('event',array`) method but i need to create a custom event in magento then how can i create custom event in magento.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for a event, you will need create a custom module with an event observer

[Magento Developper’s Guide (Lesson 11) – Events and Observers in magento](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105)

[Customizing Magento Using Event Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

If you want to Dispatch your own Event

> Mage::dispatchEvent('some_event_handle', array('customer'=>$customer, 'order'=>$order));

Then create a custom module to listen for this event (some_event_handle) see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3459/